# how to get entity by key in google app engine using go language

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

now I add some entity in datastore using Go language,
I can query all entity, but I want get a entity by key, 
how to get entity'key and query by key like this: select * from Blog  where key=?

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
g := Blog{
Title: r.FormValue("title"),
    Content: r.FormValue("content"),
}
_, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Blog", nil), &g)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See the [Datastore documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/overview#Introducing_the_Go_Datastore_API) for the Go Runtime:

```
var b Blog
err := datastore.Get(c, key, &b)
```